# c# connect into MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to connect **MySQL** in **C#** develope in **Expression Blend 4** 
but i get following error ?

```
try
        {
            string serverConnection = "SERVER=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; UID=xxx; PASSWORD=xxx; DATABASE=xxx;";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(serverConnection);
            conn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully connected");
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:"+ex.Message);
        }
```

Here is the error:

```
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts
```

Comment: Any inner exception? can you connect to mySql from another MySQL Managers?

Comment: Yes it works fine in another. There is one exception here conn.Open();

Comment: Is MySql using the default port 3306?

Comment: Yes it is, local server worked but remote server says these error

Comment: Did you  config your MySQl to accept remote connections to your IP? you need to grant permissions first. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: Can you post the MySQL config file (without pwd) i think it's a MySQL Configuration problem. Can you connect to that remote MYSQL from your machine (with any other client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for connection strings is as follows,

> Server=myServerAddress; Port=1234; Database=myDataBase; Uid=myUsername; Pwd=myPassword;

The most likely issue is that you are trying to remotely connect to your MySQL server in which case make sure it allows for remote connections, and then you must check and make sure the user you are trying to login as is allowed to connect from either your public IP or any public IP.

**NOTE:** I know this response is 2 and 1/3 years late, but I wanted this to be here for anyone else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think its more of like the placement of the parameters.

The [standard](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/) format specified is this:

> Server=myServerAddress; Port=1234; Database=myDataBase;
>   Uid=myUsername; Pwd=myPassword;

You need to change it like this:

```
string serverConnection = "SERVER=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; DATABASE=xxx; UID=xxx; PASSWORD=xxx;";
```

Try to change and see if that works :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it doesn't work same as before :(